# Stripe Automatic Confirmation and order fulfillment without Webhooks?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

The stripe documentation says when using payment intent using automatic confirmation you should Asynchronously fulfill the customer’s order using webhooks.

If i'm offering a service e.g. ability to download a file once purchased then why do I need to monitor for the `payment_intent.succeeded` webhook?

If payment succeeded in the following `handleCardPayment` function then is there still a possibility for the charge to fail? Why shouldn't I allow the user to download the file straight away if the payment has succeeded?

```
var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
var clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  stripe.handleCardPayment(
    clientSecret, cardElement, {
      payment_method_data: {
         billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
      }
    }
  ).then(function(result) {
     if (result.error) {
       // Display error.message in your UI.
       } else {
       // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
   }
 });
});
```

Maybe I've not understood how the handleCardPayment works. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

When using `handleCardPayment`, the issue is not so much that the payment might fail, it's that it might *succeed* but your code *doesn't know about it*.

`handleCardPayment` kicks off several asynchronous steps — showing the user a dialog to authenticate a payment with their bank, processing the actual charge against their card, and closing the dialog. It's only after all that completes does the Promise resolve and your function that receives `result` executes.

Consider the case where:

- the customer clicks Pay
- `handleCardPayment` is called
- the customer sees a dialog from their bank to authenticate the
  payment
- they do that, and they consider that their payment is now complete,
  and they close their browser immediately.

In this case, your code will never execute, but Stripe still processed the charge. So you don't know that the payment happened and you can't fulfil the order.

That's why it's important to use webhooks, so you get notified asynchronously when the payment completed, even if the user closed their browser mid-process and your code after `handleCardPayment` never got a chance to run. Alternatively you can use the [manual confirmation flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#manual-confirmation-flow), where the steps are split up and the actual charge isn't processed until your server makes a separate API call.

Comment: so in the interim between the charge having been processed and the webhook firing if the user was to view the order it would still show as incomplete or unpaid since my code never got the chance to update the order status if user closed the browser mid-process. I'm assuming the webhook fires instantly but what if there's some delay, the user would be seeing an order that unpaid?

Comment: Yes. The webhook would be fired extremely quickly in most cases though, as close to instant as possible.